# How to add 2 arrays?

Tags: java

I have an array with 3 players, and 2 others arrays `array_power_1` and `array_power_2`.

```
String[] array_Player = {"Celine", "Amelia", "Sandrine"};   
int[] array_power_1 = {4,8,10};
int[] array_power_2 = {1,4,4};
```

In fact, I would like to add for each player the number of power.

For example:

```
Celine 5 
Amelia 12
Sandrine 14
```

I think that I have to create an empty array ?

```
int[] array_Power = new int [array_power_1.length + array_power_2.length];
```

However, it doesn't work...

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] array_Player = {"Celine", "Amelia", "Sandrine"};
    
    int[] array_power_1 = {4,8,10};
    int[] array_power_2 = {1,4,4};

    int[] array_Power = new int [array_power_1.length + array_power_2.length];


    display(array_Player, array_Power);
  }


  public static void display(String[] array_Player, int[] array_Power ){

    for(int i=0; i<array_Player.length; i++){
      System.out.println(array_Player[i] + " " + array_Power[i]);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final int SIZE = 3;
        String[] array_Player = {"Celine", "Amelia", "Sandrine"};
        int[] array_power_1 = {4,8,10};
        int[] array_power_2 = {1,4,4};
        
        if(array_power_1.length == SIZE && array_power_2.length == SIZE && array_Player.length == SIZE) {
            int[] array_Power = new int [array_power_1.length + array_power_2.length];
            display(array_Player, array_Power, array_power_1, array_power_2);
        }
    }

    private static void display(String[] array_Player, int[] array_Power, int[] array_power_1, int[] array_power_2) {
        for(int i=0; i<array_Player.length; i++){
            array_Power[i] = array_power_1[i] + array_power_2[i];
            System.out.println(array_Player[i] + " " + array_Power[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Added `if(array_power_1.length == SIZE && array_power_2.length == SIZE && array_Player.length == SIZE)` because it will proceed only if `SIZE` of all array are same.